# Magento 1.9.2.3 - How to include Guest customer in Observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, guest-checkout

My code for payment method only  whose customer **group 9**,

```
<?php
class Gta_FilterPaymentGateway_Model_Observer
{
    public function paymenter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $currentCustomerGroup = (int)Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    
            if (($observer->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'paytm_cc') && ($currentCustomerGroup !== 9)) 
            {
                $result = $observer->getResult();
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
    }
}
```

Here how can i include the guest customers if condition?

Workout :

```
<?php
class Gta_FilterPaymentGateway_Model_Observer
{
    public function paymenter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $currentCustomerGroup = (int)Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $checkcustomer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
    
            if (($observer->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'paytm_cc') && ($currentCustomerGroup !== 9) && $checkcustomer  ) 
            {
                $result = $observer->getResult();
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
    }
}
```

Any help thanks.

Comment: if you just want to know if the customer is guest or not. trigger getCustomerIsGuest() in Mage_Sales_Model_Order I believe that can get customer instance of order.

Comment: @JigarPatel I have one doubt, in my observer i set whose customer group 9 that people only able to pay right, here why guest customer eligible to pay?

Comment: @JigarPatel Is this the correct way to do? https://justpaste.it/88wwz or https://justpaste.it/995br any help thanks